# How to create an if statement with jquery.cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

So I have this code down below and I now I want to implement it with [jquery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to fire this code only once in a month, how can I accomplish this?

```
$(function() {
    var $follow = $(".follow-1");
    if (!$follow.hasClass("active")) {
        $follow.click();
    }
});
```

Comment: `if (timestamp you get from cookie is older than 1 month) { .click() }`

Comment: Also what is once a month? Every 30 days, every 17th of the month?

Comment: yes, every 30 days @mplungjan. @marc-b I'm a newbie with jquery so I didn't undertood much of the code should I do something like this? `if ($.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });) { .click() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely mean something like this:

```
$(function() {
   var cook = $.cookie("seen"); // get the cookie
   if (!cook) { // if no cookie show
    var $follow = $(".follow-1");
    if (!$follow.hasClass("active")) {
       $follow.click();
    }
    $.cookie("seen","yes",{"expires":30}); // set cookie to expire in 30 days
  }
});
```